# Make gcc -MM ouput the relative path for the object filename

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm using **gcc** to generate the dependencies of my Makefile. But it doesn't use relative paths. For example,

```
gcc -MM util/test.c ui/resource.c
```

generates

```
test.o: util/test.h
resource.o: ui/resource.h
```

while, to allow **make** to find dependencies, it sould generate something like this:

```
util/test.o: util/test.h
ui/resource.o: ui/resource.h
```

Is there any way to make gcc behave like the second example?

Answer (score 6):

From [`man gcc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)

> **-MT** target
>       Change the target of the rule emitted by dependency generation. By default CPP takes the name of the main input file, deletes any directory components and any file suffix such as .c, and appends the platform's usual object suffix. The result is the target.
>
> An -MT option will set the target to be exactly the string you specify. If you want multiple targets, you can specify them as a single argument to -MT, or use multiple -MT options.
>
> For example, -MT '$(objpfx)foo.o' might give
>
> $(objpfx)foo.o: foo.c
>
> **-MQ** target
>       Same as -MT, but it quotes any characters which are special to Make. -MQ '$(objpfx)foo.o' gives
>
> $$(objpfx)foo.o: foo.c
>
> The default target is automatically quoted, as if it were given with -MQ.

So, you can use for example

```
gcc -MM -MT util/test.o util/test.c
gcc -MM -MT ui/resource.o ui/resource.c
```

*Update*:

There are several possibilities, if you want all dependencies in one file.

You can execute the `gcc -MM` in sequence and redirect the output

```
( gcc -MM -MT util/test.o util/test.c; gcc -MM -MT ui/resource.o ui/resource.c ) >file.deps
```

You can postprocess the output with sed or perl

```
gcc -MM util/test.c ui/resource.c | perl -p -e 's,^(.+?)\.o: (.+?)/\1\.c.*,$2/$&,;' >file.deps
```

You can redirect the first output and append the following to some file

```
gcc -MM -MT util/test.o util/test.c >file.deps
gcc -MM -MT ui/resource.o ui/resource.c >>file.deps
```

Comment: No good... this way I need to generate one depend file for each source file. I wanted to generate one single depend file from all my sources...